# disable cd tab completion for __pycache__ in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

when I type

```
cd path/to/python_package/
```

and press tab to try to fill `path/to/python_package/only_module` for example, I am stopped dead in my tracks! By

```
$ cd path/to/python_package/
__pycache__/  only_module/
```

How can I make tab completion for `cd` ignore `__pycache__`? In the future I imagine I will realise there are other folder names I may want to add to the "blacklist" too, does zsh support blacklisting folder names like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore some patterns in completions by tuning [completion styles](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Standard-Styles) with the [`zstyle` built-in](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fzutil-Module). There are [examples in the zsh guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide06.html#l156).

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:cd:*:*' ignored-patterns '__pycache__'
```

Under default settings, zsh tries a second round of completion if there are no matches the first time, and the second round does not honor `ignored-patterns`, so you can still complete `__pycache__` after `_` (or whatever it takes for `__pycache__` to be the sole potential completion).

Comment: If I want to ignore more folders, do I add them after `'__pycache__'` like a space-separated argument list?

Comment: @theonlygusti Yes (`… ignored-patterns __pycache__ .cache`), or you can use a pattern like `… ignored-patterns '(__pycache__|.cache)'`.